# powershell, audio loop until button is pressed

Tags: powershell

what I need is to combine PlayLooping (or PlaySync) with a OK button, - more precisely loop audio file until the OK button is pressed

something like this

```
(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer('C:\Windows\Media\Ring01.wav')).PlayLooping();
```

and

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Output = $wshell.Popup("ALARM")
```

I assume that the solution will be quite easy ;) thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Powershell runs synchronously, your code will be executed sequentially. You just need to stop the sound after user presses Ok button.

```ps
$sound = New-Object Media.SoundPlayer('C:\Windows\Media\Ring01.wav')
$sound.PlayLooping();
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Output = $wshell.Popup("ALARM")
if($Output -eq "1")
{
    $sound.Stop()
}
```

Comment: Nice; quibble: `.Popup()` returns an `[int]`, so `-eq 1` is better; as an aside: with _only_ an OK button, as in this case, the return value is _always_ `1`, so there's no point in checking it.